# How to get MODIFY_PHONE_STATE on rooted device

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I have rooted phone where i am running my application which need to answer a incoming phone call. Currently getting an exception like this:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10174 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
```

As i have a rooted phone and it is require a runtime permission so how i can add it without showing a permission dialog as describe [here](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=zh-CN&sp=nmt4&u=https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview&xid=17259,15700021,15700124,15700149,15700168,15700173,15700186,15700191,15700201&usg=ALkJrhg0FFAVfQjgVj1RyFkfJCZBQK2n2w)